# How to get list of admin user list in Jenkins via any script?

Tags: jenkins, automation, jenkins-cli, jenkins-api

I am trying to get the list of admin user list and also the users and their level of permissions in Jenkins.

Can anyone help me with any script available please.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve all the users using groovy script as follows:

```
import hudson.model.User

allUsers = User.getAll()
adminList = []

for (u in allUsers) {

    if (u.hasPermission(Jenkins.ADMINISTER)) {
        adminList.add(u)
    }
}

println(adminList)
```

Comment: Sagar, thanks for the reply, but it would never show that who are all having the admins level access.

Comment: never showed that who are all having the admins level access.

Comment: The names in the list are admins

Answer (score 1):

I use the following script to create a admin user list. The script also works with Matrix-based security.

```
import hudson.model.User

def inst = Jenkins.getInstanceOrNull()
def strategy = inst.getAuthorizationStrategy()
def adminUserList = User.getAll().findAll { user ->
    strategy.hasPermission(user.id, Jenkins.ADMINISTER)
}
```

All users with their permissions are accessible as follows:

```
import hudson.model.User
import hudson.security.Permission
def inst = Jenkins.getInstanceOrNull()
def strategy = inst.getAuthorizationStrategy()
strategy.getMetaPropertyValues().find { it.getName() == 'grantedPermissions'}.each {
    // it.value is a map with permission as key and the corresponding users as value
    print(it.value[Permission.READ])
    print(it.value[Permission.WRITE])
    print(it.value[Permission.HUDSON_ADMINISTER])
}
```